# Extend Schengen visa to go to the UK for a short stay

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, europe, transition-of-visa-status

I am Jamaican and I am currently in Europe on a Schengen visa. I have been invited to the UK next month for 2 weeks. How much will it cost to extend my schengen visa? I am a musician and may play percussions on two shows while I am in the UK. What is the cost variation?

Comment: What kind of visa are you currently in the Schengen area with?

Comment: Are you asking how much it costs to get an entertainers visa for U.K.?

Comment: Are you aware that the UK is not a part of the Schengen area?